# Why do we use base 32 or base 64 to represent data instead of 0s and 1s?

Tags: java, serialization, binary, base64, radix

I recently wrote a program that serializes some data (java objects) and saves the resulting string in a text file. The information is serialized in base 64 therefore the data ends up looking something like this:

rO0ABXBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBwcHBzcgAab3JnLmJ1a2tpdC51dGlsLmlvLldyYXBwZXLyUEfs8RJvBQIA.

I understand somewhat what base 64 means, however, since this is gibberish, why doesn't the text file or computer show 0s and 1s from the beginning? If I understand the underlying process correctly, all information on the computer is stored in the form of 0s and 1s somewhere anyway since that is the only way computers can ultimately store information. Isn't base 64 simply a way of reading and interpreting bytes? Why go through the trouble of making my text editor read the bytes saved on the computer, turn them into letters (ultimately making the document shorter for me) and then displaying it in the form above? Even though base 64 results in a visually more compact way of displaying the information, no one can read the base 64 text anyway and the file still has the same exact size.

Comment: This isn't clear.  Are you asking why your text editor doesn't show you the file as a sequence of 0s and 1s?

Comment: Apologies if my question wasn't quite clear. I understand that the text editor displays the letters and numbers because it is told to do so, my question is rather why we bother generally in the first place to tell a text editor to display a collection of bytes in an alphabetical way if we can't read it anyway. I hope that makes more sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base64 is used for sending 8bit data through systems which do not understand and/or mangle 8bit data. e.g. most older email systems assumed 7bit text, and will trash your 8bit email.

b64/b32 are not intended to be storage formats. They've massively waste of space. Encoding a value into base64 will blow up its size by about 33% on average. They're TRANSMISSION formats, to make sure that your 8bit data gets through 7bit systems intact.

Consider a simple text sequence: `abc`. assuming ASCII text, that's

```
0x61      0x62       0x63      (hex)
01100001  01100010   01100011  (binary)
97        98         99        (decimal)
```

When jammed together into a file, your bits will be simply

```
011000010110001001100011
```

If this sequence of 8bit-bytes gets sent through a dumb 7bit transmission medium, and then re-instated to a 8bit system, all sense of which bits belong to which byte will be lost. You'd end up with

```
0110000   1011000  1001100  011
```

because the receiving 8bit system will have no idea that the original data was 8bit. It'll see bits coming in from a 7bit system, and split those bits up into 7bit sequences. Now your values are hosed:

```
0110000   1011000  1001100  011                   (binary)
48        88       88       corrupt/missing bits  (decimal)
30        58       58       corrupt/missing bits  (hex)
```

Those values would correspond to the ASCII chars

```
RS X X
```

and be nothing like your original text.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer! Why does converting information into a base64 format blow up its size? Isn't it still the same information and bytes being stored?

Comment: More modern examples of formats that can't incorporate arbitrary 8bit data include XML and JSON. Since they can incorporate arbitrary textual data, base64 is used to turn binary into text.

Comment: @MagnusQ Yes, it's the same data, but no it's not the same bytes. Normal bytes have 256 possibilities (so allow packing 8 bits per value), and base64 chooses 64 of those that are likely to transmit well (so allow packing just 6 bits per value). Three binary bytes becomes four base64 characters.

Comment: base64 = 6 bits. turning 8bit bytes into 6bit bytes meas you have to add extra characters to preserve the overflow bits. that works out to a 33% overhead.